# QtCreator Designer signal/slot connections inconsistent with generated code

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm working on a Qt project in QtCreator. The project has a dialog box with several UI elements, some of which have to be enabled/disabled according to what the user does. (i.e. If the user selects a radio button, then the form field has to be enabled.)

When I add a new signal/slot connection or delete an existing through the Qt Designer tool, the change shows up just fine in the preview. When I compile the application, though, the window still behaves exactly as it did before.

I investigated this by checking out the `ui_WindowName.h` file that the Qt Designer creates. Near the end of the `setupUi` function is a set of `connect()` calls. These `connect()` calls are consistent with the slot and signals that existed earlier today, but they do not reflect the changes I have made through Qt Designer since.

If I manually change the `ui_WindowName.h` file, then the UI works. But, of course, my changes get overridden if I ever try to chance anything from Qt Designer.

Even when I quit QtCreator and open it again, the Designer still shows the changed slot/signal connections while the auto-generated code does not reflect the changes.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there some way to delete whatever cache the Designer is storing or something to get things back in sync?

Thanks!

(One other thing: I'm using the stand-alone Qt Creator, not trying to develop in Visual Studio. The only other similar problem I could find on the web was from someone developing in Visual Studio, which doesn't support the automated signal/slot stuff.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual, the answer is obvious once you realize it.

I moved the project in the course of working on it. There's a .pro.user file that keeps track of where the project is located. Without realizing that, I moved it along with the rest of the files.

As a result, I was editing one copy of the project and running the other.

The moral of the story: If you move a Qt project, remember to update your .pro.user file.

(Or you can just delete it. Qt Creator will prompt you to re-create it when you open the project.)

Comment: the kind of things which waste you an entire afternoon, and that you cannot justify it (even to yourself).